Dual boot Asus Rog Strix G16 G614JV using Ubuntu - BIOS changes
I know of a user (Alfarrow, Speakers don't work on Asus ROG Strix G16 G614JV in Ubuntu 22.04), who installed Ubuntu 22.04 on an Asus Rog Strix G16 G614JV.
I wish to dual boot the exact same machine using Ubuntu, but asking how he managed this (privately) is not possible.
Alfarrow, if you read this post, please reply.
I have done extensive research but am still a bit unsure.
If anyone else could confirm what settings must change in the BIOS, I would be grateful.
The system:
Windows 11,
RST enabled PCIE SSD
Secure Boot on, Fast Boot on
Using Windows Disk Manager, I have created a partition for Linux.
Thanks everyone

Update to the kernel and its accompanying firmware to at least v6.7 or higher
